# Swift: How to access `UITableViewCell` from other UI Function

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` which have some section inside. In one of the section, there is a `UIDatePicker`. I try to implement the reset date to my datePicker but i get some litle problem. I need to access `cell.accessoryType` from my `UIDatePickerAction` . Below my snippet code :

```
@IBAction func datePickerClaimedAction(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
    self.dateClaimedBy = datePickerClaimed.date
    self.labelDateClaimed.text = programProperties.showDateFormatter.string(from: datePickerClaimed.date)

    self.buttonDeleteDateClaimed.isHidden = false

    // some code to access `cell.accessory`
}
```

I read some question about this but its still not work. Any other suggest or answer will help for me. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Does this code is from cell class or from tabelViewDateSource class ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it.

First, i make a variable `var indexRow: IndexPath?`. And then. I cast the `indexPath` from

`override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { .. }` function.

I need cell from section 2 with row 4 so i add case like:

`if indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 4 { 
     self.indexRow = indexPath 
 }`

In my DatePicker Action, I use this

`let cell = tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexRow!)`

So I can get access to `cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator` to specific cell. Thanks in Advance

Comment: That's a pretty bad solution. You are strongly discouraged from calling the delegate method `tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt)` yourself. Use a appropriate model which mirrors the state of the `accessoryType`. Then change the model and reload the row or entire table view.

Comment: @vadian thanks for your suggestion. But can you give me a sample. I have a complicated UITableView, i think this is the simple and proper way

Comment: @vadian And what the effect calling the delegate method like that? I' searching but i dont have any regarding topic. Can you explain ?

Comment: `tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt)` is called by the data source and is supposed to be called **only** by the data source. There is another method `cellForRow(at:` in `UITableView` which can be called by custom code. Basically you are discouraged from calling any framework delegate methods yourself.

Comment: @vadian I use a static tableview, but ok i will try another way with `cellForRow` method. But i know it will make my line code more and more

Comment: If you are using static cells you are able to assign an `IBOutlet` to the accessory view.

Comment: @vadian what the mean accessory view? I think you downvote me before you realy now my case

Comment: Sorry, I meant an outlet to the static cell.

Comment: @vadian the `cellForRow` truly doesnt simple in my case. I just use static tableview, but the section and content are realy much more and comlicated logic. And I just need call the contents of them in first load. Now i just need how to get A specific cell just only to hide the accessory and do another logic in the datePicker action